# What should I do if user manually change the DOM element attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, sails.js

I'm using sails to create my Webapp.

Used `<form>` to collect and submit to my server. I'm wonder what if user change the element from inspect mode?

For example:

```
<form>
   <input name="m_1_firstname" type="text" class="form-control required" placeholder="First Name"/>
   <input name="m_1_lastname" type="text" class="form-control required" placeholder="Last Name"/>

   <input name="m_2_firstname" type="text" class="form-control required" placeholder="First Name"/>
   <input name="m_2_lastname" type="text" class="form-control required" placeholder="Last Name"/>
</form>
```

by using `m_1_xxx` to determine the first and second user, so I'll map it on server, and the result will be

```
m: {
   1: {firstname: 'firstname1', lastname: 'lastname1'},
   2: {firstname: 'firstname2', lastname: 'firstname2'}
}
```

offcourse I have a add user button, to append `m_3_xxx, m_4_xxx` and the following.

now the problem is, what if the user edit my `name` value to something else? then I might get unexpected result and mess up the data.

**What is the correct way to manipulate the input data? How to handle the user from editing element and do submit?**

or I should add the custom value to each input? such as:

`$('input[name="m_1_firstname"]')[0].mycustomname = 'm_1_firstname'`

then collect the input's name by using: `input.mycustomname` ?

In this way, the mycustomname can be see from inspect mode? if they didn't know my code.

Comment: Don't trust *any* data sent by the client, because they can modify it to be anything. Verify on the server instead. Anything in client-side Javascript will not be sufficient.

Comment: Remember that one may not even be using a browser to communicate with your server.